# How to override File type in typescript so that I can have more fields added to its type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So, I have a state that is responsible for temporaly saving a File but that thing is that when I send this file to the backend service I also need to assign a few new fields to this File object (these fields are needed in the backend)

What I initially did was

> interface FileDocument extends File {   documentTypeId: string
> fileKey: string   documentSide: string }

But it doesn't work because at build time it breaks saying that documentTypeId isn't of type File

How should I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented all the required props in the interface like below?

```
interface FileDocument extends File {
    documentTypeId: string
    fileKey: string
    documentSide: string
}


const fileDoc: FileDocument = {
    documentTypeId: 'test',
    fileKey: "",
    documentSide: "",
    lastModified: 0,
    name: "",
    webkitRelativePath: "",
    size: 0,
    type: "",
    arrayBuffer: function (): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
        throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
    },
    slice: function (start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob {
        throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
    },
    stream: function (): ReadableStream<any> {
        throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
    },
    text: function (): Promise<string> {
        throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
    }
}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADYQCIHsECuAthOMhAB6QgAmAzmpigN4BQyHyN%20xpYAKgE8ADhACSNAFzI6YKKADm7TjCYBpCIOmz5IJZy48S4AMrAaEbXMWsAvqwcJcIWclVY8Caeg9G%20yAF5kNgNuQmMBEXEpZABySFlYgBplDncIDS1kACJslNC-U3NLHLzU5Aw4WQBZXBpgVQgYgAZ8zhA4Emlcto4AdwgAIwBrYDAAJQhKsGAANwgABTgwAAtusoM6YAAvEtbysCj13uQ4KCg4QQAhAhgYaGkYAhAEGedkAAoASmkFqFwiMA6BAADwAQXOlxud2gAD5guUDKt-n1kCAIKiAKLnXBQD7ZVDPV7Ad4gXBgZDAIjCLARJoAOmyXwA3OVbCc6BhgEhHkS3iBPrIzmAAPzSEDEQbQJLkWhitGS6XIJzgPhCUTynSKH7IK4YXCDBEGJErFFojHIbH-PEEvkkgVkilUmkQOk0RkstkcuQQTq8l78z46yZwGhwQZYEw%20zoguAgQTwkLGjjI3Co9FYnE2wkB%201o8mU6m0vgMpmsgzsg6UMD%204nvb6-f6A4EgrV6ROIzip9MWq24-E5usOgvO4uq91ltl2VhAA)